# Sutherland–Hodgman Algorithm Variation for Non Degenerate Polygon Output

Tags: algorithm, clipping

I need a fast polygon clipping implementation against an axis aligned rectangle and I've implemented Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm based on my particular data set and it's 40 to 100 times faster than [ClipperLib](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter11.html) and other generic polygon clipping algorithms, but the output is a degenerate polygon in some cases:

[image]

results in:

[image]

Is there a variation of Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm to generate multiple polygons instead of a degenerate one or any fast and simple way to transform the degenerate polygon into multiple polygons?

Comment: Usually we are happy with the degenerate output polygons since a correct polygon fill handles them just fine. Splitting up the degenerate polygon is non-trivial -- actually more difficult than the SH clipping.

Comment: Does something like the [Weiler-Atherton clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm) satisfy your needs?

Comment: can you please add an example in a form of array of coordinates pairs so there will be a reproducible example for the ones willing to help?